# ERROR The requested URL could not be retrieved - when accessing URL by using PROXY

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, apache-2.4, centos7

I'm getting this error message:

```
ERROR
The requested URL could not be retrieved

The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http://xxx

    Read Timeout

The system returned: [No Error]

A Timeout occurred while waiting to read data from the network. The network or server may be down or congested. Please retry your request.

Your cache administrator is root.
```

When I go to the same URL without proxy - everything does work great.

I'm using `CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503` with `Apache/2.4.6`

Comment: It can happen for some reason your proxy server is not able to access that URL. Try from the server `curl -iv http://xxx` to see if it is able to reach the website.

Comment: @alphamikevictor thank you for your comment. it does work with proxy but only for a few minutes and then I get the message. I encode video on my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I'm getting this error only in Firefox if script works longer than 15 minutes.

You have to send anything to Firefox browser or you gonna get the error described above.

It can be done with [flush - php function.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php)